# Wrapping slow synchronous I/O for asynchronous UI consumption

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, task

I have an external library which does slow I/O (serial+wireless, etc...), with no async (even old-style) in the API.

I'm trying to work out a way to wrap this for easy consumption from UI, so that my user can connect without the whole UI freezing, and preferably so I can just `async-await` it.

But I'm reading conflicting advice, like "only use Task.Run for CPU-bound operations".

So, what should I do? Just `async-await` a `Task.Run` (omitting `ConfigurAwait(false)`), or implement a whole `INotifyCompletion`?

Comment: I think this depends on every use case. I use a Thread object when dealing with serial commincation because I want to listen, not just send, or you could use events. But doing a http request is fine to just await in Task.Run(). It kinda depends on the work you are doing.

Comment: A cursory Google search yielded multiple articles about how you shouldn't use `Task.Run` for non-CPI-bound operations, and I also found an [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) from Microsoft stating that creating an asynchronous wrapper to synchronous methods is a bad idea

Comment: @fstam There's no reason at all to require a thread just because you're reading IO instead of sending it.

Comment: It should however be made clear that the blog post linked by @MindSwipe assumes that you are able to modify the library, i.e. add "real" async methods. IMO, if you just want to put a long-running call off the UI thread, Task.Run() is not a bad idea, even for I/O. At least you have to somehow deal with the fact that an API call may block the calling thread.

Comment: @Servy I case of a serial you might. The dot net SerialPort class starts a thread of it's own and notifies consumers of received data through an event.

Comment: @Servy the key here is full duplex comminication instead of half.

Comment: @fstam No, it doesn't create a new thread.  It just uses inherently asynchronous IO so that *no thread is needed* to have a thread sitting around doing nothing waiting for IO.  That's the whole point of an asynchronous API.  The type of IO you're performing doesn't change that.

Answer (score 7):

It's important to distinguish from "ideal" and "real-world". Ideally, `async` should be all the way. Ideally, all I/O should be asynchronous and not use up thread pool threads, and `Task.Run` is only used for CPU-bound methods. Ideally, `async void` should only be used for event handlers.

In the real world, sometimes you have to mix `async` and sync due to lack of time (or library support). In the real world, not all I/O operations have asynchronous APIs, and even shiny-new types like `HttpClient` use thread pool threads to work around old DNS resolution code that no one wants to take the time to fix. In the real world, `async void` is sometimes a cleaner approach than bare continuations, even when it's not being used for event handlers.

In your case, I would just use `Task.Run` and not worry about it. The main problems with `Task.Run` are when you're using it in an ASP.NET app or in a library, where it can interfere with other usage of the thread pool. Since you're working on a UI application, using `Task.Run` for I/O isn't "ideal", but it's a perfectly fine option as a tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks. I'll commit my code with the comment "Absolution from Stephen Cleary" :)